# PHP sessions not acknowledging userID

Tags: php, html, session, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am trying to make an SQL query where it only selects data from the table if the userID matches for that of the session and that of the table.

My problem is that it doesn't acknowledge a userID variable associated with the session and returns a blank string. It also does this for fName, lName and password but not for others including username and level which it gets these values from the database and displays the correct ones associated with the session. Why are some columns names working in my code but not others?

I have tried echoing the userID out and nothing but when I echo the username out it displays it.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "connection.php";
    if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
    $userID = $_SESSION["userID"];
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID = '$userID'");
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          echo "ID: " . $row["userID"]. ";
        } 
    }
    else{
         echo "No records";
    }
?>
```

That's just a part of my code and I was just borrowing the if statement from W3Schools to check things to see if they would work

adminPage.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION ["level"];

    if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
        if($_SESSION["level"] != "admin"){
            header("Location: users.php");
        }
        else{
            header("Location: adminPage.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
        echo"
        <p class = \"big\"> Login </p>
        <hr>
        <form action = \"loginInsert.php\" method = \"post\">
            Username: <input type = \"text\" name = \"username\"><p>
        Password: <input type = \"password\" name = \"password\"><p>
        <button type = \"submit\" value = \"Submit\"/> Sign in </button>
        <hr>
        Not a member? <a href = \"signUp.php\"><button type = \"button\"> Sign Up </button></a>
        </p>
        </form>";
    }
    else{
        header("Location: admin.php");
    }           
?>
```

loginInsert.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "connection.php";
    if(isset($_POST["username"])){
        $username = $_POST["username"];
    }
    if(isset($_POST["password"])){
        $password = $_POST["password"];
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
        $_SESSION["level"] = $row ["level"];
        if ($_SESSION["level"] == "admin"){
            header("Location: admin.php");
        }
        else{
            header("Location: users.php");
        }
    }
    else{
    header("Location: login.php");
    }
?>
```

[image]
Thank you for taking time to read my question

Comment: When and where do you assign `$_SESSION["username"]` & `$_SESSION["userID"]`?

Comment: SQL Injection, *ahoy*! Sanitize your inputs.

Comment: That query should be able to return at most one row – so why are you using a _loop_ to output it?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm new to php do I have to assign these? Sorry if this is a silly question

Comment: @CBroe Because userID returns nothing so nothing is outputted? It goes to the else in the loop and displays "No records"

Comment: Yes @Dward - you have to assign these when you have determined who/what they are. Until you assign them they are not set and don't exist.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Could you provide more information about how I do this? (:

Comment: When a user logs in @DWard (we haven't seen your login.php) and is successful you would do something like `$_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];` or you might use data you get back from the database to fill out those variables. Make sure you have `session_start()` at the beginning of every page.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I included my login.php. 
So I would include ^^ code in login page or the other page?

Comment: And now where exactly are you setting `$_SESSION["userID"]` …? (And how is that even a login? You are assuming that `$_SESSION["username"]` is already set there – but where that value gets written into the session – also nowhere to be seen …)

Comment: login.php needs a `session_start()` because you're checking for a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Edit 3: PLEASE INCLUDE ALL OF YOUR FILES. LIKE USER.PHP

> I am trying to make an SQL query where it only selects data from the table if the userID matches for that of the session and that of the table.

Based on your question, I have to wonder if you initialized your session variables? Please post your login.php file.

I had a similar problem earlier in which my session variables were dropping mysteriously. A big thing I recommend is doing the session_start() on all your pages. I have a belief that your issue is either (A) you didn't assign it or (B) you didn't *really* recall your values in the database for those. More likely the latter.

Use an object to get values. Do you have something like this for login

```
$user = new user();
$_SESSION['UserName']=$_POST['UserName'];
$_SESSION['UserMail']=$_POST['UserMail'];
```

And for create account you only inserted values? If so you probably want to add this to your insertUser.php file or something similar to it so that the object, $user, has his or her values correctly in place.

```
$user->setUserName($_POST['UserName']);
$user->setUserMail($_POST['UserMail']);
```

Regarding the comments: @esqew I may be wrong but I think mysqli automatically sanitizes the query. You should also use ->fetchAll(); if you're using a loop.

Edit: Sorry I can't comment because not enough street cred, but I want to emphasize- Please make sure you know exactly what the superglobal variables do. $_SESSION is created every time you start a session and are destroyed when you end it. Let's say you created a user in insertUser.php and said

```
$_SESSION['UserName']=$_POST['UserName'];
```

If you only put that in insertUser, the $_SESSION variable would not exist when you log in, unless you put that inside your login.php file as well. $_SESSION is very versatile and expendable, but you must always remember talk directly to the database not to PHP. For example, this is what I wrote for my website:

```
        require_once "conn.php";
        $req=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserMail=:UserMail AND UserPassword=:UserPassword");//:thepassword
        $req->execute(array(
            'UserMail'=>$this->getUserMail(),
            'UserPassword'=>$this->getUserPassword()
            ));
        if($req->rowCount()==0){//None matched, 0 selected
            //header("Location: ../index.php?error=1");
            //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Incorrect Email or Password.');</script>";
            header("Location: ../index.php?error=1");</script>";
            return false;
        }
        else{
            while($data=$req->fetch()){//Fetches closest row from table
                //PERSON ASKING QUESTION MAKE SURE YOU HAVE SOMETHING LIKE THIS
                $this->setUserId($data['UserId']);
                $this->setUserName($data['UserName']);
                $this->setUserPassword($data['UserPassword']);
                $this->setAge($data['Age']);
                $this->setUserMail($data['UserMail']);
                $this->setUserLocation($data['UserLocation']);
                header("Location: Home.php");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit 3: PLEASE INCLUDE ALL OF YOUR FILES. LIKE USER.PHP

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it wasn't working properly because I hadn't set the session variables up correctly. Thank you for your help :)